# Criticar campo vazio no PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Olá. Eu tenho um código em Php que em determinado momento me retorna um valor de um input:

```
<input type="text" style="color:chocolate" size="1" id="note1" name="note1" class="mynote" value="<?php print preg_replace("/\"/", "&quot;", $message['note']); ?>" />
```

Eu trabalho com o valor resultante do value. Eu preciso criticar se o valor do value for vazio, não mostre nada.

Eu já tentei o seguinte:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.comjquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#note1').hide();
      $("input").change(function(){
         $( "input option:input").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")!=""){
               $("#note1").hide();
            }
            else {
               $("#note1").show();
           }
        });
      }).change();
   });
</script>
```

Alguma opção neste Jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro eu trocaria um trecho do seu código para `htmlentities`, para não haver problemas com a impressão de `value`:

```
<input type="text" style="color:chocolate" size="1" id="note1" name="note1" class="mynote" value="<?php echo htmlentities($message['note']); ?>" />
```

E eu colocaria a ação no submit do formulário, e não no `change` de um elemento:

```
$('#note1').hide();
  $('#seu_formulario').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     $( "input option:input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()){
           $("#note1").hide();
        }
        else {
           $("#note1").show();
       }
    });
  }).change();
```